# Lock specific applications or settings using a password

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to lock specific settings in Android such as Turning on/off debugging mode, Enabling WIFI etc.

Is it possible to do it programmatically using either `adb` or a background application?

I found [Smart App Protector](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sp.protector.free&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5zcC5wcm90ZWN0b3IuZnJlZSJd) application in the Android Market thus I supposed it is possible,even without rooting the device.

Can someone provide an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way the SmartAppProtector works is that it handles and recieves the Intents used to start those applications. Some options are handled via Intents, but most are not. This means that yes, this is possible for certain options, but no, this is not possible for all options.

For instance, you can turn WIFI on or off with an Intent. Therefore, SmartAppProtector's technique could be used for it. However, USB Debugging is not handled via an Intent (as far as I know); therefore, it cannot be.

One caveat of this is that you ***could*** protect the entire Settings application. But that would block all access to all Android Settings, rather than a specific one. Mind you, this does not stop programmatic access to these settings, just access via Intents (programmed or clicked).

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic